# How to find out sid with substatus in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a table containing the following columns: `id, sid, subcode, subStatus`

`Sid` stand for student id. I want student with `finalStaus.Finalstatus` is base on last subcode of that sid.

In first case sid is 5 and Finalstatus is Fail.Here lastsubcode is 4.

In second case sid is 3 and finalstaus is promo.Here lastsubcode is 3.

Subcode can be 1,2,3,4 .....

```
Id    SId   SubCode  SubStatus
1     5       4       Fail
2     5       3       pass
3     5       2       pass
4     5       1       fail
5     3       3       promo
7     3       2       promo
8     3       1       pass
```

How to find out sid with substatus in sql?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Sql Server` then you should use `Row_number()` ranking function as:

```
with CTE as
( Select sid, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY subcode DESC) AS lastsubcoderow,
         subStatus
 From Student
 )
 Select sid ,subStatus  from CTE
 where lastsubcoderow = 1
```

Check [DEMO](http://rextester.com/XXBV81942) here

Comment: Not only SQL Server supports window functions (as they are named in the SQL standard). Postgres, Oracle, DB2, Informix, Teradata also support them (just to name a few)

Comment: Thank u so much.I want exactly same.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want in most any RDBMS:

```
SELECT t.sid, t.substatus
FROM table t
JOIN (
  SELECT i.sid, MAX(i.subcode) AS max_subcode
  FROM table i
  GROUP BY i.sid
) m ON m.sid=t.sid AND m.max_subcod=t.subcode
```

The internal query selects the rows with the highest subcode for each student. The main query then joins this with the orginal table to retrieve the corresponding substatus.